# R function, that given an input uses it for future calculations

Tags: r, dataframe

For my project I would require some help that I cannot find on google. Is there a code where the starting value of a chain of commands (previous output (using a shift function)* value (from another column) = output) is set to be 1, so that the next command has a previous output to reach back on, to start the chain? Whatever I have tried, with setting the first row = 1 etc., has not worked... :(

Thank you very much for the Help,

Ferdinand

For more details: In a dream world Debt$returnp for row 1 would be 1, the output in row 2 would be output row 1 (1) * Debt$return (1.015) and so on for every following row. Would anyone know a string of code that would do that?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2vFW.jpg

Comment: Probably need some more context to be helpful, but see `dplyr::lag` or `purrr::reduce` for functions that may do what you want. If you have a particular set of data and operation that you can share, we might be able to give more of an answer.

Comment: `lag` has an argument `default` that provides a default value for rows that don't exist (e.g. before the start of the data). Careful with `coalesce` since it will also overwrite missing values that occur in rows that do exist (i.e. in the middle of your data)

Comment: I learned something today, thanks :) only knew `.init` in reduce... I'll delete my comment to avoid confusion.

Comment: Sorry, I just added more info now, thank you fir all the help <3

Comment: adapted my answer below. I think it does what you're looking for <3

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Don't share data as images. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

Building on comments above and making some assumptions about what you are trying to achieve, how's this working for you:

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

values <- c(2,4,6,10)
purrr::reduce(
  .x = values,
  .f = function(state, input){return(c(state, input*dplyr::last(state)))},
  .init=1
)[-1] # the [-1] is just there to remove the initial value from your output
```

---

// UPDATE:
this should adapt the above to what you're showing in the screenshot:

```
library(tibble)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

Debt <- tibble(
    # Week, debt, Date, Diff, Perf
    return = c(NA_real_, 1.015, 1.092, 1.005)
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    returnp = purrr::reduce(
      .x = return[-1], # start with the second entry and skip that initial <NA>
      .f = function(state, input){return(c(state, input*dplyr::last(state)))},
      .init = 1
    )
  )
```